# How do you switch to Preact from React with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, preact

I've created a project in meteor using `meteor create --react`, and was wondering how to switch to Preact from React, as I've tried following this guide: [PreactJS Guide to Switching](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started/#integrating-into-an-existing-pipeline). However, I keep getting an error on loading client-side, where it states `Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined`, I figured this had something due to the babel setup section in the guide, but still haven't managed to solve it, this issue seems akin to [here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-compat/issues/541), however, I'm not using webpack and so would like to avoid this solution.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: An [older Meteor forum post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-do-you-switch-from-react-to-inferno-preact/39241/5) has solved this but not very detailed. If you can't find a solution you may ask in the forum for help.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this works although as you said it is missing a lot of detail, should be noted that you need to have the destructured import for render from Preact, but otherwise works like a charm! Thanks a lot though.